# ¿Como uso dicccionarios en Python como comandos?

Tags: python, diccionarios

He intentado usar diccionarios para un bot como si fueran comandos y así evitar usar un if para cada comando, pero de mis muchos intentos no he podido lograrlo, puesto que en cada if que hice hago uso de diccionarios en cada uno y luego mando el diccionario a la funcion que manda el mensaje con los parametros de ese dict. Por ejemplo:

```
@client.callbacks.event("on_text_message")
def on_text_message(data):

msg = data.message.content
nick = data.message.author.nickname
message = {
    'chatId': data.message.chatId
}
#command es el mensaje del usuario y params es el parametro que da

command = msg.split(' ')
params = command[1:]
introducir el código aquí
command = command[0] 

    elif command == "-cat":
      response = requests.get('https://some-random-api.ml/img/cat')
      json_data = json.loads(response.text)
      url = json_data['link']
      file = url_like(url)
      message.update({
            'message': ..., 
            'file': file,
            'fileType': "image"
        })
    send_message(data.comId, message)
    return
   
    elif command == "-kiss":
        message.update({
        'message': f"<$@{nick}$> besó apasionadamente a  <${name_pr(pr_t)}$>...",
        'replyTo': data.message.messageId
    })
```

se me complica saber como poner lo que hay dentro de cada if en un diccionario y luego tratar de usar cada dict en busqueda del comando y luego usar lo que hay dentro, intente usar funciones

```
dict = {
   'kiss':{ 'run': kiss(..) }
}
```

Pero no se si una buena forma de tratar de solucionar ya que cada if es distinto y tendria que hacer muchas funciones que luego no usare..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este tipo de problemas tiene una solución más o menos típica, que vamos a examinar usando un simple ejemplo: un programa que lee y ejecuta tres comandos:

- conectar
- desconectar
- fin

Cada comando tiene una cantidad variable de parámetros.

El primer paso es definir el formato común para las funciones que implementaran los comandos. En este caso, elijo que cada función reciba una cantidad variable de parametros y retorne un entero que indique el resultado.

Las tres funciones entonces son:

```
def fun_conectar(*args):
    print("Conectar con parametros:")
    for param in args:
        print(param)
    return 1

def fun_desconectar(*args):
    print("Desconectar")
    for param in args:
        print(param)
    return 0

def fun_fin(*args):
    print("Fin")
    sys.exit(0)
```

Las funciones no hacen más que imprimir un título y sus parámetros.

Ahora, el diccionario de comandos es este:

```
comandos = {"conectar": fun_conectar,
            "desconectar": fun_desconectar,
            "fin": fun_fin}
```

La llave es el nombre del comando y el valor es la función (sin paréntesis). Con esta base para agregar nuevos comandos basta definir la función correspondiente y agregarla al diccionario.

Ahora sólo queda entrar en un ciclo. En cada iteración leemos una línea del teclado y la dividimos en comando y parámetros. El comando lo buscamos en el diccionario, y si lo encontramos, lo ejecutamos:

```
while True:
    linea = input(">Ingrese comando:\n>").lower()
    cmd, *params = linea.split()
    if cmd in comandos:
        rc = comandos[cmd](*params)
        print(f"Retorno = {rc}")
    else:
        print(">Comando no reconocido\n")
```

produce:

```
>Ingrese comando:
>conectar a b c
Conectar con parametros:
a
b
c
Retorno = 1
>Ingrese comando:
>desconectar b
Desconectar
b
Retorno = 0
>Ingrese comando:
>fin
Fin
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Me despejaste bastante la mente, si cada comando depende de otras funciones debo hacer una busqueda de ello en la funcion "conectar" o lo pongo en el mismo diccionario del comando?

Comment: @HiroshiKumasuki. Las funciones de apoyo que necesites las llamas directo. El diccionario solo contiene los comandos que escribe el usuario.

Comment: Muchas gracias nuevamente!